# Python export a dictionary with datasets to different tabs in excel

Tags: python, database, dictionary, tabs, export-to-excel

I have a dictionary composed of several dataframes

```
dictionary = ({'df1':Dataframe, 'df2':Dataframe, 'df3':Dataframe, 'df4':Dataframe, 'df5':Dataframe})
```

I would like to export the dictionary to an excel file where every dictionary is in a different tab and of course the key name should be written somewhere to distinguish between them.

Any suggestion would be really helpful!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write multiple sheets in an Excel file using pandas (see [example at the bottom](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)):

```
import pandas as pd
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_1')
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_2')
```

Instead of writing df1/df2/... explicitly you can simply loop over your dictionary of data frames:

```
import pandas as pd
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
    for key, val in dictionary.items():
        val.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=key)
```